# How to sort an array of arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, parse-platform

I'm getting back a set of arrays from Parse.  They are named vid1 through vid10.  I am trying to sort them so when I place the respective elements in the respective custom arrays they will be in order.  Please help me with 1.  Where to implement and 2. How?  Here is my code......

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
        query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (vid:Array?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if vid != nil
            {
                for items in vid!
                {
                    if !(items["vid1"] == nil)
                    {
                        if let myfav1 = items["vid1"] as? NSArray
                        {
                            let id = myfav1[0] as! String
                            let rank = myfav1[1] as! String
                            let title = myfav1[2] as! String
                            let description = myfav1[3] as! String
                            let image = myfav1[4] as! String
                            self.vidRankArray.append(rank)
                            self.vidIdArray.append(id)
                            self.vidTitleArray.append(title)
                            self.vidDescriptionArray.append(description)
                            self.vidImageArray.append(image)
                        }
                    }
                    if !(items["vid2"] == nil)
                    {
                        if let myfav2 = items["vid2"] as? NSArray
                        {
                            let id = myfav2[0] as! String
                            let rank = myfav2[1] as! String
                            let title = myfav2[2] as! String
                            let description = myfav2[3] as! String
                            let image = myfav2[4] as! String
                            self.vidRankArray.append(rank)
                            self.vidIdArray.append(id)
                            self.vidTitleArray.append(title)
                            self.vidDescriptionArray.append(description)
                            self.vidImageArray.append(image)
                        }
                    }
```

***** UPDATE ******

This is what I'm getting back from Parse as vid!.  This is what I want to sort

```
[<UserVideos: 0x7fa068f15430, objectId: hbqSBoHsxa, localId: (null)> {
    userObjectId = 4k5eUtDPnz;
    vid1 =     (
        "yWfsla_Uh80",
        1,
        "EXO_CALL ME BABY_Music Video",
        "Download on iTunes : KOR https://itunes.apple.com/album/the-2nd-album-exodus/id979878364 CHN ...",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yWfsla_Uh80/default.jpg"
    );
}, <UserVideos: 0x7fa068f171e0, objectId: 7S9oT6DePb, localId: (null)> {
    userObjectId = 4k5eUtDPnz;
    vid2 =     (
        "dF3fc0K_7Nw",
        2,
        "blackqueen's 2ne1 kpop mix cover dance",
        "On the day of the foreign embassies in Korea.. blackqueen's 2ne1 kpop mix Invitation performance \Uc8fc\Ud55c\Uc678\Uad6d\Ub300\Uc0ac\Uad00\Uc758 \Ub0a0 \Ube14\Ub799\Ud038\Uc758 2ne1 \Ubbf9\Uc2a4 \Uacf5\Uc5f0.",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dF3fc0K_7Nw/default.jpg"
    );
}, <UserVideos: 0x7fa068f17a90, objectId: MHZOmKu3Qw, localId: (null)> {
    userObjectId = 4k5eUtDPnz;
    vid3 =     (
        MBNQgq56egk,
        3,
        "BIGBANG - \Ub9e8\Uc815\Uc2e0(SOBER) M/V",
        "Available on iTunes @ http://smarturl.it/BIGBANGMADE_D Available on Spotify @ http://sptfy.com/BIGBANGMADE_D #  BIGBANG #  \Ube45\Ubc45 #SOBER #\Ub9e8\Uc815\Uc2e0 ...",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MBNQgq56egk/default.jpg"
    );
}, <UserVideos: 0x7fa068f18240, objectId: e5TiEbjdhr, localId: (null)> {
    userObjectId = 4k5eUtDPnz;
    vid7 =     (
        PfUlE2LlGro,
        7,
        "TVXQ! \Ub3d9\Ubc29\Uc2e0\Uae30_Catch Me_Music Video",
        "TVXQ! new album 'Catch Me' to be released on September 24th at noon (Seoul Time) through various music websites! \U266a Download on iTunes ...",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PfUlE2LlGro/default.jpg"
    );
}, <UserVideos: 0x7fa068f189f0, objectId: UKvjXI5TXh, localId: (null)> {
    userObjectId = 4k5eUtDPnz;
    vid10 =     (
        PfUlE2LlGro,
        10,
        "TVXQ! \Ub3d9\Ubc29\Uc2e0\Uae30_Catch Me_Music Video",
        "TVXQ! new album 'Catch Me' to be released on September 24th at noon (Seoul Time) through various music websites! \U266a Download on iTunes ...",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PfUlE2LlGro/default.jpg"
    );
}, <UserVideos: 0x7fa068f19200, objectId: zCQTXde30Q, localId: (null)> {
    userObjectId = 4k5eUtDPnz;
    vid8 =     (
        gAal8xHfV0c,
        8,
        "EXO_\Ub291\Ub300\Uc640 \Ubbf8\Ub140 (Wolf)_Music Video (Korean ver.)",
        "Download on iTunes : https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/the-1st-album-xoxo/id651337773 \U266a For more information \U261e smtown hompage ...",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gAal8xHfV0c/default.jpg"
    );
}]
```

Comment: There are far more problems with this code than just trying to sort them.

Comment: Please elaborate. Currently it executes fine the vids are just not in order.

Comment: down voting because a) there's way more going on in there than the question suggests and b) without the update there was no visible array to sort and c) WITH the update (and the accepted answer) I see you're not sorting an array of arrays, but an array of UserVideos objects. The title REALLY needs to be changed because it just misleads people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have a hard time keeping all of those arrays in sync. I would make a Video class with properties videoID, rank, title, description, and image. Then sort on whatever property you want. If it's rank, it'd look like this:

`let sortedVideos = videos.sort { $0.rank < $1.rank }`

If for whatever reason you do need arrays with the attributes pulled out, you can use map:

`let titles = videos.map { $0.title }`

Comment: Thanks.  I've been trying this for a while that's why I thought I could rank them before I get to the custom arrays.  Maybe I didn't give enough info.  What I'm getting back from Parse as vid! is actually several arrays or video information that has been saved for that user. So vid is an array of arrays vid1 - 10.  Is there anyway I can sort them directly from Parse?

Comment: Please see update.  How do I sort what I'm getting from Parse by element[vid1] <

Comment: Are you trying to sort them in order by the rank? Check out this link for an implementation: https://gist.github.com/cuomo456/251c2581562408342563

Comment: As posted on your git - This works amazing.  Wasn't familiar with mapping from another class although I know how to do it for a custom table view cell. Thanks. ****  Follow Up *****  If you could give some tips on comparing counts on vid1 id's and how to display to top 20 that would be awesome.